# Embedding Unity game into web page after checking if statement

Tags: php, html, authentication, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is check if the user is logged in so the game could load to play. The page works if I dont check for the login status but the else statement in the code below just displays a white page with nothing on it. The code in the else statement is copied straight from the generated html file from unity. I am new to php and html so I dont really know what changes I would need to make for it to work in my current layout so any help would be very useful. I know the code in the else statement works if its just in a separate html file with no login check.

```
<div id="main">
<h3>Get started with your website</h3>
<ol class="round">
<li class="one">

    <?php if(!logged_on()) { //This if statement works
        echo '<li><a href="/logon.php">Please login to play</a></li>' . "\n";
    }

    else //This doesnt work
    {

         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <title>Unity Web Player | Cool Ninja Platformer</title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ssl-webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/jquery.min.js'></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
            var unityObjectUrl = "http://webplayer.unity3d.com/download_webplayer-3.x/3.0/uo/UnityObject2.js";
            if (document.location.protocol == 'https:')
                unityObjectUrl = unityObjectUrl.replace("http://", "https://ssl-");
            document.write('<script type="text\/javascript" src="' + unityObjectUrl + '"><\/script>');
            -->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                var config = {
                    width: 960, 
                    height: 600,
                    params: { enableDebugging:"0" }

                };
                config.params["disableContextMenu"] = true;
                var u = new UnityObject2(config);

                jQuery(function() {

                    var $missingScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".missing");
                    var $brokenScreen = jQuery("#unityPlayer").find(".broken");
                    $missingScreen.hide();
                    $brokenScreen.hide();

                    u.observeProgress(function (progress) 
                    {
                        switch(progress.pluginStatus) 
                        {
                            case "broken":
                                $brokenScreen.find("a").click(function (e) 
                                {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    u.installPlugin();
                                    return false;
                                });
                                $brokenScreen.show();
                            break;
                            case "missing":
                                $missingScreen.find("a").click(function (e) 
                                {
                                    e.stopPropagation();
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    u.installPlugin();
                                    return false;
                                });
                                $missingScreen.show();
                            break;
                            case "installed":
                                $missingScreen.remove();
                            break;
                            case "first":
                            break;
                        }
                    });
                    u.initPlugin(jQuery("#unityPlayer")[0], "game.unity3d");
                });
            -->
            </script>
            <style type="text/css">
            <!--
            body {
                font-family: Helvetica, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
                background-color: white;
                color: black;
                text-align: center;
            }
            a:link, a:visited {
                color: #000;
            }
            a:active, a:hover {
                color: #666;
            }
            p.header {
                font-size: small;
            }
            p.header span {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            p.footer {
                font-size: x-small;
            }
            div.content {
                margin: auto;
                width: 960px;
            }
            div.broken,
            div.missing {
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;
                top: 50%;
                width: 193px;
            }
            div.broken a,
            div.missing a {
                height: 63px;
                position: relative;
                top: -31px;
            }
            div.broken img,
            div.missing img {
                border-width: 0px;
            }
            div.broken {
                display: none;
            }
            div#unityPlayer {
                cursor: default;
                height: 600px;
                width: 960px;
            }
            -->
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p class="header"><span>Unity Web Player | </span>Cool Ninja Platformer</p>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="unityPlayer">
                    <div class="missing">
                        <a href="http://unity3d.com/webplayer/" title="Unity Web Player. Install now!">
                            <img alt="Unity Web Player. Install now!" src="http://webplayer.unity3d.com/installation/getunity.png" width="193" height="63" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="footer">&laquo; created with <a href="http://unity3d.com/unity/" title="Go to unity3d.com">Unity</a> &raquo;</p>
        </body>
    </html>
    }

    ?>

</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: html is not valid PHP, you need to close the php tag after the else, then reopen it again for the ending brace... tbh you should be reading error logs before you even come to this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before trying to print explicit HTML without using `echo` you have to close your php code block with `?>`. And before doing more php code you have to open it again `<?php`.

Another issue is that you need `<!DOCTYPE html...` to be the *first* line of your page.  So having `<div id="main">` and so on above it is going to cause a big problem.  So put that at the top always.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php 
if(!logged_on()) 
{ 
    echo '<li><a href="/logon.php">Please login to play</a></li>' . "\n";
}
else 
{
?>
    <head>
    all whatever html you want to have explit
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks, it took a while to understand why the <?php and ?> are in those positions but now I understand and it helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative method, you can have your Unity game itself check your authentication status with your site's server.  This is arguably superior, because the unity player would otherwise continue to function after a php session may have expired, so long as the page isn't reloaded.

See [Unity Web Player and Browser Communication](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/UnityWebPlayerandbrowsercommunication.html).

1. Execute arbitrary javascript from your game to send an ajax request to you server.  The request will include all your local browser cookies, including the php session token.
2. The ajax url is a data service on the server which replies with authentication status.
3. Parse the result, change your game's behavior based on web authentication status.

As a side benefit, you have now implemented DRM into your game.  Congratulations.